# Alert.Button is not convertible to Alert.Button?

Tags: button, swiftui, alert

i try to insert a simple alert to a button, when my Textfields are empty, but I receive the Error message Alert.Button is not convertible to 'Alert.Button?'...

I would say that my code is 100% correct, but.. Xcode is not on my side..

This is my code,..

```
struct ContentView : View {

@State private var name = String()
@State private var pw = String()
@State private var myAlert = false

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ZStack{
            VStack{
               //deleted code//
                Button(action: {
                    if self.name == self.fileName
                    {
                        print("Hey \(self.name) - your password is \(self.pw)")
                    } else {
                        if self.name.isEmpty && self.pw.isEmpty {
                            self.myAlert = true
                            print("broken!")
                        }
                    }
                    .alert(isPresented: $myAlert) {
                        Alert(title: Text("ERROR!"), message: Text("Username und Password are empty"), dismissButton:.default(Text("Ok")))
                    }
                })
                //deleted code//
}}}}}
```

Does anybody know where the mistake is? I can't found them.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) There is no fileName?

2) The button is missing a Label:

```
  Button(action: {...}) {  
  //Label here
}
```

Comment: oh, sry - filename is on top xD i tried to minimize the code and delete everything which is not important for the problem. But the if's confused me.. Thanks, it was the label <.<